# How to make the code work for all rows?

Tags: c#

I have the next code, who suppose to change rows from a text file when the `checkbox` from a `checkedListBox` are selected. And the code work, but just for some rows, and I don't understand what is the reason because don't work for all.

```
private void checkedListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string installerfilename = string.Format("{0}{1}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "installer.ini");
    IEnumerable<string> inilines = File.ReadAllLines(installerfilename).AsEnumerable();

    string selectedItem = checkedListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    bool IsChecked = checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Contains(selectedItem);
    //bool IsChecked2 = inilines.Contains("#product=");

    if (IsChecked)
        inilines = inilines.Select(line => line == string.Format("#product={0}", selectedItem)
                                           ? Regex.Replace(line, string.Format("#product={0}", selectedItem), string.Format(@"product={0}", selectedItem))
                                           : line);

    else
        inilines = inilines.Select(line => (line == string.Format("#product={0}", selectedItem) || line == string.Format(@"product={0}", selectedItem))
                                           ? Regex.Replace(line, string.Format(@".*product={0}", selectedItem), string.Format(@"#product={0}", selectedItem))
                                           : line);

    string strWrite = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, inilines.ToArray());
    File.WriteAllText(installerfilename, strWrite);
}
```

An example where don't work properly it's on the next rows:
When Aerospace Toolbox, Communications Blockset, Communications Toolbox are checked on the checkedListBox, in installer.ini I have next changes :

```
#product=Aerospace Toolbox => product=Aerospace Toolbox
#product=Communications Blockset => product=Communications Blockset
#product=Communications Toolbox => remain the same      #product=Communications Toolbox
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you compare the value of `selectedItem` in cases where your application works to cases where it doesn't work, is the value accurate? What do you mean by "don't work at all". What happens? Does the application crash? If so, what's the error? Possibly something wrong with how you're trying to change the values in `inilines` / `strWrite` as well.

Comment: "don't work for all" **NOT** "don't work at all"

Comment: the value is accurate, and  "don't work for all" you can see the last part, the mode how are modify the rows fron installer.ini

Answer (score 1):

I would change the following

```
  string selectedItem = checkedListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    bool IsChecked = checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Contains(selectedItem);
```

with

```
bool IsChecked = checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Contains(checkedListBox2.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: when I do this I have the next error: "The name 'selectedItem" does not exist in current context"

Comment: @ben `SelectedItem`, with a capital S not a lower case one. Referencing the property of the `checkedListBox2`, rather than the string property `selectedItem` you created in the snippet you posted in your question.

Comment: all I do was to replace what you say to do

Comment: so?? if you can give me a full answer I will be so thankfull

Comment: I assume that error is in the if conditions because I removed the string selectedItem =.... code. I think you should go through the code and replace references to selectedItem with checkedListBox2.SelectedItem. How are you binding the objects to the checked list box?

Comment: @Yohannes thank you, but the only problem was in else where I supposed to have  line == string.Format("product={0}",  not  line == string.Format("#product={0}",  the difference is just an #